# AWS - Unable to access S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting, access-control, bucket

I am getting an error when trying to access the bucket using url.
Click http://awsweatherbucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ to get the error details.
The bucket policy is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForPublicWebsiteContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsweatherbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me resolve the issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It looks like you got it fixed.

Comment: Hi, this is working for me. Can you share anymore details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is listing the bucket content as an XML response, which is the correct behavior, when the bucket is not configured for static website hosting.

To load the actual website, you can directly call index.html at:

http://awsweatherbucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/index.html

To correctly configure the bucket, please refer to the AWS [user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html).

Alternatively, if you are using the AWS CLI, you can also configure the bucket using the [following command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/website.html):

```
aws s3 website s3://awsweatherbucket/ --index-document index.html --error-document error.html
```

*Note, you don't have an error-document in your bucket, but you should. That's where the user will be redirected when they are trying to access a page that doesn't exist.*